# Linux: automated sftp file transference by an ssh connection

Tags: linux, file, ssh, sftp

I need to make a crontab script (executed automatically and periodically) that should find the latest changed file of a folder and then transfer it to another machine, using an sftp connection.
The first part of the problem is solved by extracting the name of the desired file:

```
cd $myFolder
output=$(find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort -rn | head -n 1)
filename=$(echo $output | cut -d'/' -f 2)
```

But the second part is difficult, because I cannot find the way to type the value of `$filename` variable in a Linux sftp connection and also the user/password in a non-interactive way. Saving it into a temporary file may be a good solution.

Is there any better alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution:**

To obtain the filename:

```
filename=$(ls -t . | head -1)
```

To transfer the data to the remote server:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# A copy of the $sourceFile is sent to the $targetPath by using the scp command (secure copy)

set timeout 20

set sourceFile [lindex $argv 0]
set targetPath [lindex $argv 1]
set user [lindex $argv 2]
set password [lindex $argv 3]

# connect via scp
spawn scp $sourceFile "$user@$targetPath"
#######################
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "$password\r"
  }
}
interact
```

The user authentication is delegated to the script that uses this script, and can be made by the generation of a public/private rsa key pair in the remote server, and then using it: Read next link: [SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to monitor the
directory and trigger on *modify*. The file name can be fed to `rsync` or
`scp`. Example:

```
inotifywait      \
  --quiet        \
  --event modify \
  --format '%f'  \
  --monitor watch_directory |
  while read FILE; do \
  scp watch_directory/$FILE host:/destination;
  done
```

Comment: inotify is good for real-time synchronization after events related to the file system, and rsync synchronizes the file system when it is executed. scp command is the best one for my purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `scp` instead of `sftp` - it uses the same protocol but is more suitable for non-interactive use.

You can find the last modified file in a directory with only `ls`, if the directory only contains files (no subdirectories):

```
output=$(ls -t "$myFolder" | head -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use curl to upload the file to the remote server via sftp, and pass the login credientials (username and password) in the command like so:

```
curl -T uploadfilename -u username:password sftp://sitename.com/myfile
```

Comment: It´s a good idea, but I have it disabled: curl: (1) Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl